# If L/K is algebraic field extension, is L(B)/K(B) also algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Seems a naive question, but I get stuck there..

> Say $M/L/K$ is a tower of fields, $L/K$ is algebraic, $B\subset M$. ($B$ is not necessarily algebraic independent over $K$ or $L$.) Is $L(B)/K(B)$ also algebraic?

My thought is as follows: take $h(b_1,...,b_n)=\frac{f(b_1,..,b_n)}{g(b_1,...,b_n)}\in L(B)$, say all coefficients form a finite subset $C\subset L$.Then $f,g\in K(C)[B]$. Clearly $[K(C):K]<\infty$. If we can show $[K(C,B):K(B)]<\infty$, then we are done. And we can see elements in K(C)[B] are clearly linear combinations of basis elements of K(C)/K with coefficients in K[B]. But how can we carry over to the field of fractions?

I see that's really a naive question.. Being algebraic is preserved under division.. Thanks for everybody's attention..

Comment: The same polynomias whose roots are generators of $L/K$ are in $K(B)[x]$.

Comment: I am sorry? I don't see the link with my question.. Can you be more explicit? Thx~

Comment: $L/K$ is algebraic if every $a\in L$ is the root of some polynomial $f\in K[x]. $ Then everything in $L$ is algebraic over $K(B)$.  Moreover, everything in $B$ is algebraic over $K(B)$.  Since $L(B)$ consists of finite sums, products, and inverses of elements of $L$ and $B$ and sums and products of algebraic elements are algebraic, the result follows.

Comment: What Michael is saying is like: $L=K(S)$, with all the elements os $S$ algebraic over $K$. Because $K\subseteq K(B)$, the elements of $S$ are algebraic over $K(B)$ also. But $$L(B)=K(S)(B)=K(B\cup S)=K(B)(S).$$